# Server Error (500) when using s3 aws amazon to store media and static fil

Tags: django, amazon-s3, server, storage

I got **Server Error (500)** when trying to launch any django page with DEBUG=FALSE, even with default admin page.

my static files and media files are configured to upload to s3 aws storage

Anyone has encountered this problem ? Please give me some advice

Many thanks

Comment: When you turn debug to false django stops serving files. You'll need to setup web server like Nginx or Apache to serve your django web app

Comment: Yes @Danoram is right you have to use nginix or apache to serve you files.